# ZF3 Nginx Serve index.php As Download File

Tags: php, linux, nginx, debian, zend-framework3

I installed debian 8 with nginx and php 7 for creating an endpoint with zendframework. When i follow the website i have to add these to my virtual host config in nginx. Like i did see the code below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/endpoint/html/public;

    server_name my_ip;

    location / {
          index index.php
          try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }

location @php {
        # Pass the PHP requests to FastCGI server (php-fpm) on 127.0.0.1:9000
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/endpoint/html/public/index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }}
```

But when i visit the website its downloading the index.php instead of executing the index.php.

I hope anyone can help me resolving this issue.

Comment: `index` inside the `location` makes internal redirect.

Comment: @Deadooshka can you tell me how i should fix this ? This is the info from the original github https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

Comment: I'm not sure you need that `index` there since I cant see proper `location` for `.php`

Comment: @Deadooshka dunno. But when i dont use the zf configuration with the [at]php its working. when putting it back its downloading the file.

Comment: I think logic of this config is bad because if a client requests real php file then it will get a php-script itself. You need at least default php-handler `location \.php$ {}`

Comment: @Deadooshka what will be default config if i follow the zendframework ? Can you share the correct one which i can use ?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files see last example for `try_files`

Comment: @Deadooshka I dont now what you mean . Could you replace the config and add the full config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to replace the `fastcgi_pass` value with `socket path` instead of server address and port.

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

Then restart your `php7-fpm` by type this command

```
sudo systemctl restart php7-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dolly-aswin,

Thx it worked replacing the 127.0.0.1 to the php-fpm sock

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/endpoint/html/public/index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

My ZendFramework 3 is now working on Debian 8 with Nginx (PHP 7).

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to adjust with PHP7. I will edit my answer, and could you accept it?

Comment: @DollyAswin thx again for the great support. If it was not fixed by the end of day i had to install apache again:).